# scan function in theano, recurrent neural net

Tags: python, theano, recurrent-neural-network

I've been trying to use scan in theano for implementing a RNN (the example is adapted from here: https://github.com/valentin012/conspeech/blob/master/rnn_theano.py)

```
def forward_prop_step(x_t, s_t_prev, U, V, W):
    u = T.dot(x_t,U)
    s_t = T.tanh(u+T.dot(s_t_prev,W)) 
    o_t = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(s_t,V))
    return [o_t[0], s_t]
Q = np.zeros(self.hidden_dim)
init = theano.shared(Q)
[o,s], updates = theano.scan(
    forward_prop_step,
    sequences=x,
    outputs_info=[None, dict(initial=init)],
    non_sequences=[U, V, W],
    truncate_gradient=self.bptt_truncate,
    strict=False)
```

Now, what I tried to do is implement an RNN where the output variables directly influence each other (`o_{t-1}` and `o_t` are linked by weights). I tried to implement it like this:

```
def forward_prop_step(x_t, s_t_prev, o_t_prev, U, V, W, Q):
    u = T.dot(x_t,U)
    s_t = T.tanh(u+T.dot(s_t_prev,W)) 
    o_t = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(o_t_prev,Q)+T.dot(s_t,V))
    return [o_t[0], s_t, o_t[0]]
R = np.zeros(self.hidden_dim)
init = theano.shared(R)
S = np.zeros(self.word_dim)
init_S = theano.shared(S)
[o,s,op], updates = theano.scan(
    forward_prop_step,
    sequences=x,
    outputs_info=[None, dict(initial=init), dict(initial=init_S)],
    non_sequences=[U, V, W, Q],
    truncate_gradient=self.bptt_truncate,
    strict=False)
```

However, it doesn't work and I don't know how to fix it.

The error message is:

> File "theano/scan_module/scan_perform.pyx", line 397, in theano.scan_module.scan_perform.perform (/home/mertens/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.2--amd64-x86_64-with-debian-7.6--2.7.9-64/scan_perform/mod.cpp:4193)
>   ValueError: Shape mismatch: A.shape[1] != x.shape[0]
>   Apply node that caused the error: CGemv{inplace}(AllocEmpty{dtype='float64'}.0, TensorConstant{1.0}, Q_copy.T, , TensorConstant{0.0})
>   Toposort index: 10

**Edit**
This is the exact code:

```
word_dim=3
hidden_dim=4

U = np.random.uniform(-np.sqrt(1./word_dim), np.sqrt(1./word_dim), (word_dim,hidden_dim))
V = np.random.uniform(-np.sqrt(1./hidden_dim), np.sqrt(1./hidden_dim), (hidden_dim,word_dim))
W = np.random.uniform(-np.sqrt(1./hidden_dim), np.sqrt(1./hidden_dim), (hidden_dim, hidden_dim))
Q = np.random.uniform(-np.sqrt(1./word_dim), np.sqrt(1./word_dim), (word_dim, word_dim))

U = theano.shared(name='U', value=U.astype(theano.config.floatX))
V = theano.shared(name='V', value=V.astype(theano.config.floatX))
W = theano.shared(name='W', value=W.astype(theano.config.floatX))
Q = theano.shared(name='Q', value=W.astype(theano.config.floatX))

def forward_prop_step(x_t, o_t_prev, s_t_prev, U, V, W, Q):
        u = T.dot(x_t,U)
        s_t = T.tanh(u+T.dot(s_t_prev,W))
        m = T.dot(o_t_prev,Q)
        mm = T.dot(s_t,V)
        SSS = mm
        o_t = T.nnet.softmax(SSS)
        q_t = o_t[0]
        return [q_t, s_t, m]

R = np.zeros(self.hidden_dim)
init = theano.shared(R)
S = np.zeros(self.word_dim)
init_S = theano.shared(S)
[o,s,loorky], updates = theano.scan(
        forward_prop_step,
        sequences=x,
        outputs_info=[dict(initial=init_S),dict(initial=init),None],
        non_sequences=[U, V, W, Q],
        truncate_gradient=self.bptt_truncate,
        strict=False)

self.my_forward_propagation = theano.function([x], [o,s,loorky])
aaa = np.zeros((1,3))+1
print self.my_forward_propagation(aaa)
```

When I omit the output `m` from the return statement (and correspondingly the `loorky` variable plus the last `None` in `outputs_info`) everything is fine. If this is included, I get an error message ValueError: Shape mismatch: A.shape[1] != x.shape[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form the implementation is not clear to tell what's wrong in your code. 
Could you check the line here

```
o_t = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(o_t_prev,Q)+T.dot(s_t,V))
```

what is Q dimension and if it is applicable to be added to `s_t`

Comment: The problem is more I think how to pass the additional argument of o_t_prev (how to do that with outputs_info, etc.) I really don't understand the scan function.

Comment: output_info used to pass initial values to be used as previous input in the scan function. this is how you can see it. the error in your code talking about 'Shape mismatch: A.shape[1] != x.shape[0]'

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, man.
The issue was: replace `Q = theano.shared(name='Q', value=W.astype(theano.config.floatX))` by `Q = theano.shared(name='Q', value=Q.astype(theano.config.floatX))`